# Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите, пожалуйста, ошибка при запуске:

[image: после запуска rails s]

**UPD:**

Запустила bundle install. Вот такие пироги:

[image: hjjkjk]

Comment: На самом деле, уже работать с Rails под Windows это плохая идея.

Answer (score 2):

[Это **баг**.](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/143) Он исправлен в версии гема `sqlite3` за номером 1.3.10 (у вас 1.3.8).

Обновите требование к `sqlite3` в вашем `Gemfile` на версию не ниже 1.3.10.

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.10'
```

...означенная строчка "гвоздями" прибьёт версию к нужной. Но это очень жёсткое требование. Можно его чуть ослабить "пессимистическим" `~>` (считающим, что бамп предпоследней цифры, т. е. до 1.4, точно всё сломает):

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.10'
```

---

---

А ещё лучше рассмотреть возможность разработки под Rails **без**  Windows, например, в виртуальной машине с Xubuntu, Linux Mint или другим дистрибутивом Linux. По нескольким причинам.

**Во-первых**, у сообщества, как видите, не очень получается поддерживать всю Rails-среду на Windows. Регулярно всплывают внезапные проблемы, что особенно опасно для новичков. RailsInstaller отчаянно пытается исправить ситуацию, публикуя оттестированные сборки, но компоненты в них не самые свежие и могут иметь **баги**.

**Во-вторых**, скорее всего, у вас всё равно на сервере будет Linux. Поэтому есть смысл разрабатывать под ним же, дабы снизить риск возникновения багов, которые на сервере воспроизводятся, а на машине разработчика нет.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас не установлены гемы (библиотеки), выполните команду

```
bundle install
```

Если команда сообщает об невозможности найти `bundle`, установить глобально гем `bundler`

```
gem install bundler
```

после чего повторите попытку с `bundle install`.

Comment: Судя по трейсу, тут бандлер всё же есть :) Но у других может не быть.